# Understanding ドッキリにかけられている

Tags: meaning

A guy confessed to a girl he likes and she accepted it but he asked her if she is serious or not. His inner monologue went like this:

> こんなに疑心暗鬼になるのは実は「告白」にトラウマがあるからだ
>
> だから今の状況はドッキリにかけられているみたいで

I don't get the meaning of ドッキリにかけられている here. Perhaps it mean something like "I am being put in a scary situation"?

Answer (score 4):

ドッキリにかけられている = getting pranked.

ドッキリ here refers to a prank, especially rather elaborated one typically set up as part of a TV program. It's not being used as the more general mimetic word.

The quoted sentence basically means that the speaker suspects it's a prank for laugh, and not a genuine love confession.

The term is attributed to a TV program called [元祖どっきりカメラ](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%85%83%E7%A5%96%E3%81%A9%E3%81%A3%E3%81%8D%E3%82%8A%E3%82%AB%E3%83%A1%E3%83%A9).

Comment: Thank you. I wonder if there is any difference when ドッキリをかけられている is used? Also, I found examples like [this](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1415010574) where ドッキリ doesn't seem to mean "a prank."

Comment: Being startled or shocked is the original sense of ドッキリ, but it also takes on the "prank" meaning by metaphor, influenced by the history with the TV program - comparable to Candid Camera in the US. Actually, in a sense the English situation is similar: "candid" previously meant "sincere" (although this was already a metaphorical extension of the original "bright/white", from the Latin), but then came (but predating the TV show!) to mean "unposed" (of a photographed scene) or "unrehearsed" (of a recorded video scene).

Comment: On the American show, the emphasis was on the idea that the prank might entice victims to do or say something that would drop their usual facade. But a more straightforward idea is that the purpose of pranking someone is to cause surprise - so.

Comment: を and に are mostly interchangeable in this context.  I think the Chiebukuro link does use ドッキリ for prank. The rest of what's written there doesn't make much sense to me, but I guess it doesn't have to, considering it talks about a dream.